# Reasons why UITableView doesn't show scrollers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a NavigationController that stacks UIViewcontrollers that have UITableView among other UI elmeents. The tables I use are actually custom tables that use custom cell views. With this arrangement those tables don't show scrollbars of any kind even though I have configured in IB the Shows Vertical Scrollers to show them.

I've tried several ways of debugging this without success. If I print to console the value of this property (showsVerticalScrollers), it prints 1, so the property is properly set, and no, my table is not wider than its parent view, actually it's way more narrow than its parent view.

Are there reasons why a table won't show it's scrolls?... btw, this happens in iOS5 running in simulator. I'm using xcode 4.2 with SLeopard. I don't have access to an iPad to test it in the hardware but other tables I have in the same project, show their scroll bars without a problem.

**EDIT**

thanks for the answer... I did one last test and found that one of the causes for not showing a scrollbar is the number of elements shown in the table, when they fit in it without the need to actually scroll. Say if you have a table with 1 row and the vertical size of the table is too big for just one row?, then iOS won't show the scrollbar when bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide a possible solution without seeing any code, but the advice I can offer is to update your code to the bare minimum needed code to implement a UITableView and see if scrolling works, if it does, add in functionality in small increments, testing the scrolling with each new code addition till you reach the point that scrolling breaks.  Incremental testing in this fashion helps to avoid issues like this where you are unable to effectively debug your application.